# Issue with using django celery when django signals is being used to sent email?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, sendmail, django-celery

I have used the default Django admin panel as my backend. I have a Blogpost model. What I am trying to do is whenever an admin user saves a blogpost object on Django admin, I need to send an email to the newsletter subscribers notifying them that there is a new blog on the website.

**I have to send mass emails so I am using django-celery.** **Also, I am using django signals to trigger the send email function.**

But Right now, I am sending without using celery but it is too slow.

```
class Subscribers(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    date_subscribed = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Newsletter Subscribers"

    # binding signal:
    @receiver(post_save,sender=BlogPost)
    def send_mails(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
        subscribers = Subscribers.objects.all()

        if created:
            blog = BlogPost.objects.latest('date_created')
            for abc in subscribers:
                emailad = abc.email
                send_mail('New Blog Post ', f" Checkout our new blog with title {blog.title} ",
                          EMAIL_HOST_USER, [emailad],
                          fail_silently=False)
        else:
            return
```

Using celery documentation i have written following files.

My celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','travel_crm.settings')

app = Celery('travel_crm')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

Mu init file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Tasks file from docs:

```
 def my_first_task(duration):
        subject= 'Celery'
        message= 'My task done successfully'
        receiver= 'receiver_mail@gmail.com'
        is_task_completed= False
        error=''
        try:
            sleep(duration)
            is_task_completed= True
        except Exception as err:
            error= str(err)
            logger.error(error)
        if is_task_completed:
            send_mail_to(subject,message,receivers)
        else:
            send_mail_to(subject,error,receivers)
        return('first_task_done')
```

This task doesn't work because I am using Django signal to trigger the send email function, How to employ this into tasks.py

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question ... I was recently faced with similar challenge which included the complexity of a multi-tenant [schema] database [proved to be an issue with Redis]. I also tried django-celery, but it is dependent on a much older version of Celery. In addition, I wanted to send mass mail initiated by model signal post_save ... using EmailMultiAlternatives with 'bcc' and 'reply-to' features.

So now I am using the latest [as of this post] Django, the latest Celery with Redis ... running on macOS localhost with Poetry virtual env & package manager.  The following worked for me:

1. Celery: I spent several hours net searching for tutorials and advice ... among others, this one added value for me [Celery w Django](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django). Good practice to dig deeper into Celery anyway if you have not done it already.
2. Redis: This will depend on your OS and if you are developing local or remote. The Redis website will guide you to set up. I also tried RabbitMQ but found it [personally] more complex to set up.
3. The code fractions: There are 4 fractions ... *myapp/signals.py, myapp/tasks.py, myproj/celery.py, myproj/settings.py* Disclaimer: I'm a hobby programmer ... more experienced engineers may well improve on my code ... I've done some minor testing and all seems to work.

> ```
> # myapp/signals.py
> @receiver(post_save, sender=MyModel)
> def post_save_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
>     if instance.some_field == True:
>         recipient_list = list(get_user_model().objects.filter('some filters'))
>         from_email = SomeModel.objects.first().site_email
>         to_email = SomeModel.first().admin_email
>         # call async task Celery
>         task_send_mail.delay(instance.some_field, instance.someother_field, from_email, to_email, recipient_list)
>
> # myapp/tasks.py
> @shared_task(name='task_sendmail')
> def task_send_mail(instance.some_field, instance.someother_field, from_email, to_email, recipient_list):
>     
>     template_name = 'emails/sometemplate.html'
>     html_message = render_to_string(template_name, {'body': instance.some_field,}) # These variables are added to the email template
>     plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
>     subject = f'Do Not Reply : {instance.someother_field}'
>     connection = get_connection()
>     connection.open()  
>     message = EmailMultiAlternatives(
>         subject, 
>         plain_message, 
>         from_email,
>         [to_email], 
>         bcc=recipient_list, 
>         reply_to=[to_email],
>     )
>     
>     message.attach_alternative(html_message, "text/html")
>     
>     try:
>         message.send()
>         connection.close() 
>     except SMTPException as e:
>         print('There was an error sending email: ', e) 
>         connection.close() 
>
> # myproj/celery.py
> import os
> from celery import Celery
> # Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
> os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproj.settings')
>
> app = Celery('myproj')
>
> # Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
> # the configuration object to child processes.
> # - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
> #   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
> app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
> # Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
> app.autodiscover_tasks()
> @app.task(bind=True)
> def debug_task(self):
>     print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
>
> # myproj/settings.py
> ...
> ##Celery Configuration Options
> CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379//'
> CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Africa/SomeCity"
> CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
> CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
> ```